# SWT CCombo selected item highlight does not work

Tags: java, combobox, swt, highlight

I have a combo viewer based on a CCombo:

```
public static ComboViewer createComboViewer(Composite parent) {
    CCombo combo = new CCombo(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    combo.setTextLimit(2);
    combo.addVerifyListener(new UpperCaseKeyListener());
    ComboViewer viewer = new ComboViewer(combo);
    viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    viewer.setLabelProvider(new CustomLabelProvider());

    String[] strings = {"AB","CD","EF","GH","IJ"};

    viewer.getCCombo().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            String key = viewer.getCCombo().getText();
            System.out.println(key);
            String[] items = viewer.getCCombo().getItems();
            if (!key.equals("") && key.length()==2) {
                for (int i=0;i<strings.length;i++) {
                    if (strings[i].contains(key)) {
                        final ISelection selection = new StructuredSelection(strings[i]);
                        viewer.setSelection(selection); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I have a list of strings : {"AB","CD","EF","GH","IJ"} in this combo viewer.

When I type for example "AB" my item is selected from the drop-down list , but it is not highlighted with blue.

How can I make this happen?

I want that when I type an item in the combo and it is found in the list , to be highlighted with blue when I open the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `setInput` on the viewer to tell it about your content:

```
String[] strings = {"AB","CD","EF","GH","IJ"};

viewer.setInput(string);
```

In general a viewer requires both the content provider and label provider to be set and then `setInput` to be called.